# What is the difference between XmlRead (MSBuild Community Task) and XmlPeek (dotNet 4.0)?

Tags: msbuild

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlPeek:
Read inner text.
Built-in support by MSBuild in dotNet Framework.

XmlRead:
Do not read inner text.
Need MSBuild Community Task.